# Access of global variables in dart / flutter

Tags: flutter, variables, dart, global

I can't seem to access my global variables *_firestore* and *loggedInUser* from a different class in flutter / dart. From what I read in the documentation and online, this should be possible?

**Creating the global variables:**

```
   import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    
    final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
    FirebaseUser loggedInUser;
    
    class TheSlateScreen extends StatefulWidget {
```

**Trying to access them here:**

```
import 'package:theslate/screens/theslate_screen.dart';

class SlateTasks extends ChangeNotifier {

 void addTask(String newTaskTitle) {

    _firestore.collection('Test').add({
      'Task': newTaskTitle,
      'User': loggedInUser.email,
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underscore `_` before a variable name means that the variable is private.
A global variable should be a public variable, a public variable on the other hand should begin without the `_`
By changing "final _firestore = Firestore.instance" to "final firestore = Firestore.instance" you should be able to access your variable globally.

Another way to make your private variable to be accessed on global level is by adding a getter like this:
Firestore get firestore => _firestore;

Comment: OMG... I missed the underscore. Thanks for the hint with the getter method, too!